# How do I assign a Amazon EC2 security group to allow publishing using webmatrix

Tags: amazon-ec2

"Assign this instance to a security group which allows publishing using Webmatrix: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=209901"

it shows on desktop readme after "Microsoft Optimized Hosting WebMatrix AMI" booted. But the article is missing.

Thanks your help.

following is the full text readme:
 Welcome to your WebMatrix Server Instance on Amazon EC2. You can publish to this server using Microsoft WebMatrix after following these steps:
 1) Install WebMatrix on your development PC:
 2) *** IMPORTANT *** Assign this instance to a security group which allows publishing using Webmatrix: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=209901
 3) Download the WebMatrix.PublishSettings file that is on your desktop to your development PC. You can import these publishing settings into WebMatrix for one-click publishing.

Comment: Your link just redirects to www.iis.net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to this article:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/gduthie/archive/2011/04/27/webdeploy-tip-for-webmatrix-watch-out-for-port-blocking.aspx

Port 8172 must be available to the computer doing the deployment.

Add permission to the [security group](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/index.html?VPC_SecurityGroups.html) your web server is running in to allow access to port 8172 for the computer that needs to do the deployment.

Then, set the EC2 host to be in that security group.